# Return synchronously called Futures asynchronously in order of execution in queue in Dart

Tags: dart, asynchronous, stream, queue, future

```
void main() async {
  Future<void> asyncFunction(time, value) async {
    return await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: time), () => print(value));
  }

  print('1');
  asyncFunction(2, "A");
  asyncFunction(1, "B");
  asyncFunction(0, "C");
  print('2');
}
```

As per the code above, I'm trying to get the code to print as:

```
1
2
A
B
C
```

I want to execute all the functions synchronously and send the asyncFunctions (Futures) off to a sort of queue that then executes those in the order they are recieved. Each function must wait for the previous function to complete it's Future before it then itself executes.

I've been trying around with streams but not getting it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an asynchronous queue of tasks where each new task added is delayed until the previous one has completed, you can write one yourself.

```dart
class AsyncQueue<T> {
  Future<T?> _current = Future.value(null);
  Future<T> add(FutureOr<T> Function() task) {
    FutureOr<T> wrapper(void _) => task();
    return _current = _current.then(wrapper, onError: wrapper);
  }
}
```

which you can use as:

```dart
Future<void> asyncFunction(time, value) async {
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: time), () => print(value));
}
...
  var queue = AsyncQueue<void>();
  print("1");
  var f1 = queue.add(() => asyncFunction(2, "A"));
  var f2 = queue.add(() => asyncFunction(1, "B"));
  var f3 = queue.add(() => asyncFunction(0, "C"));
  print("2");
  await f3;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to make `Future.delayed(2, ...)` complete before `Future.delayed(1, ...)`.    That just isn't how time works.  What you instead could do is to rely on return values instead of side-effects, and then you could build a `List` of `Future`s and use `Future.wait` to collect the results and to print them in the original order:

```dart
void main() async {
  Future<dynamic> asyncFunction(time, value) async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: time));
    return value;
  }

  var futures = <Future<dynamic>>[];
  
  print('1');
  futures.add(asyncFunction(2, "A"));
  futures.add(asyncFunction(1, "B"));
  futures.add(asyncFunction(0, "C"));
  print('2');
  
  var results = await Future.wait(futures);
  for (var result in results) {
    print(result);
  }
}
```

The above approach has the benefit of allowing the multiple asynchronous operations to potentially run in parallel.

Alternatively, you could delay constructing the `Future.delayed(...)` objects so that each one isn't created until the previous one completes:

```dart
void main() async {
  Future<void> asyncFunction(time, value) async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: time), () => print(value));
  }

  var queue = <Future<void> Function()>[];
  
  print('1');
  queue.add(() => asyncFunction(2, "A"));
  queue.add(() => asyncFunction(1, "B"));
  queue.add(() => asyncFunction(0, "C"));
  print('2');
  
  for (var thunk in queue) {
    await thunk();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
void main() async {
  Future<void> asyncFunction(time, value) async {
    return await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: time), () => print(value));
  }

  print('1');
  print('2');
  await asyncFunction(2, "A");
  await asyncFunction(1, "B");
  await asyncFunction(0, "C");
}
```

Comment: No, I want to call those functions synchronously. They should be placed in a sort of queue so that then each executes once the previous one has completed

Comment: But this way, each one executes once the previous one is done.

Comment: Yes but then the '2' prints last because it has to wait

Comment: Oh Oh, would there be any problem with printing the '2' immediately after printing '1'?

Comment: I want it to print 1, 2, A, B, C, The letters are delayed but with different times so they each have to wait for the previous one to finish.

Comment: Check the edit.

Comment: You misunderstand. It must execute like i've written in the original code.

Answer (score 0):

OK I managed to figure something redimentary out:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:collection';
import 'dart:math';

var streamController = StreamController<String>();
Queue queue = Queue();
bool busy = false;

Future<void> asyncFunction(value) async {
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: Random().nextInt(4)));
  return print(value);
}

void main() async {
  streamController.stream.listen((letter) async {
    queue.add(letter);
    if (!busy) {
      busy = true;
      while (busy) {
        await asyncFunction(queue.first);
        queue.removeFirst();
        if (queue.isEmpty) {
          busy = false;
        }
      }
    }
  });

  print("1");
  streamController.add("A");
  streamController.add("B");
  streamController.add("C");
  streamController.add("D");
  print("2");
  streamController.add("E");
  streamController.add("F");
  streamController.add("G");
  streamController.add("H");
  print("3");
  print("-");
}
```

Gives the desired result of:

```
1
2
3
-
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
```